# Ubuntu Icon Problem and no SSH

Tags: ssh, icons

Has anyone here seen the following issue:

[image: Icon]

The system starts normally. After some time, the following issue occurs: I can't open anything, and the computer cannot be restarted

Comment: disconnect the intnet

Comment: Are you the remote user?

Comment: Yes im the Remote user.